# New repo command ( 1.22) is available

Tags: git, repo

I started getting the below warning message suddenly in my repo when I do `repo init`. I spent enough time searching about it in forums but no luck!

```
A new repo command ( 1.22) is available.
... You should upgrade soon:
```

What it is about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it have any further error message afterwards? If yes, and if it contains path to the latest files for `repo`, you can try doing

```
mv /home/user/bin/repo /home/user/bin/repo.bkp
cp /home/user/android/.repo/repo/repo /home/user/bin/repo
```

If that works, fine, else restore the backup for now. Let me know if it works.